# Error in checking an R package with `rchk`

Tags: r, cran

[`rchk`](https://github.com/kalibera/rchk/) can be used to check R
packages with compiled code. Along with other tools, `rchk` is now
used to check relevant CRAN packages and a related `Additional issues` page is linked on the the `CRAN check results` page.

When testing my package using a local installation of `rchk` I get the
following report:

`ERROR: too many states (abstraction error?) in function strptime_internal`

I have no idea of what it means. My package does not use any
`strptime` function.

I have a similar message when I check the **dplyr** or the
**jpeg** package as installed from the CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question [at rchk](https://github.com/kalibera/rchk/issues/22#issuecomment-656036156).

The message means that the function `strptime_internal` (which is an R internal function) is too complicated for 'rchk' to analyze.

Other functions will still be analysed; if you see the line `Analyzed XX functions, traversed XX states` and no other error messages, then you can consider the check a success.